# Equivalent form for the Bruhat decomposition

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive group and $B$ a Borel subgroup. The Bruhat decomposition allows us to write (where $W$ is the Weyl group):
$$ G/B = \coprod_{w\in W} BwB$$

Why is this form the same as looking at the $G$-orbit decomposition ($G$ acting diagonally):
$$ (G/B)^2 = \coprod_{w\in W} G\cdot (eB,wB)$$

I believe this generalizes. If $P_1,...,P_n$ are parabolic subgroups, then looking at the orbits of the diagonal $G$ action on $G/P_1\times ... \times G/P_n$ is the same as the orbit structure of the $P_1$ action on $G/P_2 \times ... \times G/P_n$.

Comment: As a note, the Bruhat decomposition generalizes for parabolics. And you can even replace the Weyl group with the relativized Weyl group (consisting of those terms without representatives in the parabolic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, suppose 
$$G/B = \coprod_{w \in W} B w B.$$

Then, pick $(gB, hB) \in (G/B)^{2}.$ We can find $w$ such that $g^{-1}h \in BwB$. Say $g^{-1}hB = bwB$. Then, $b^{-1}g^{-1}h \in wB$ and hence,
$$(gB, hB) = gb(eB, b^{-1}g^{-1}hB) = gb(eB, wB).$$

Hence, $(G/B)^{2} \subseteq \coprod_{w \in W} G\cdot (eB, wB)$, and the reverse inclusion is obvious.

Now, suppose 
$$(G/B)^{2} \subseteq \coprod_{w \in W} G \cdot (eB, wB).$$
Pick $gB \in G/B$. Then, for some $w \in W$, and $g \in G$,
$$(eB, gB) = (g'B, g'wB)$$
and hence $g' \in B$ and hence $gB \in BwB.$ Hence, $G/B \subseteq \coprod_{w \in W} BwB$ and the reverse inclusion is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

This is just an instance of the following general fact. Suppose a group $G$ acts *transitively* on two sets $X,Y$. Choose any $x_0\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$, and put $\def\Stab{\operatorname{Stab}_G}H_x=\Stab(x_0)$ and $H_y=\Stab(y_0)$. Then there is a bijection between on one hand the orbits of $G$ acting componentwise on $X\times Y$, and on the other hand the set of double cosets $H_x\backslash G/H_y$: the orbit of $(x,y)$ corresponds to the double coset $H_xg_1^{-1}g_2H_y$ where $g_1,g_2$ are any group elements with $g_1\cdot x_0=x$ and $g_2\cdot y_0=y$. Since the elements $g_1,g_2$ are determined up to right multiplication by $H_x$ respectively by $H_y$, the double coset associated to $(x,y)$ is well defined, and it does not change if $(x,y)$ is replaced by another point $(g\cdot x,g\cdot y)$ in its orbit. Moreover
any double coset $H_xgH_y$ corresponds to some orbit, namely that of the point $(x_0,g\cdot y_0)$, so the correspondence is surjective, and its injectivity is also easily checked.

Now in the case of the question one can take $X=Y$ the set $\def\B{\mathcal B}\B$ of Borel subgroups; since these Borel subgroups are their own normalisers, $\B$ is in bijection with $G/B$ once the particular Borel subgroup $B$ is chosen (via $gBg^{-1}\mapsto gB$), and one chooses $x_0=y_0=B$ as base point, for which $H_x=H_y=B$. Now the Bruhat decomposition says that $W$ provides a set of double coset representatives for $B\backslash G/B$, and by the general correspondence I indicated this also means that $\{\,(x_0,w\cdot y_0)\mid w\in W\,\}$ is a set of representatives for the diagonal $B$-orbits on $\B\times\B$. The element $(x_0,w\cdot y_0)$ is actually $(B,wBw^{-1})$ in $\B\times\B$, or under the map $\B\to G/B$ it is $(eB,wB)$ in $(G/B)^2$.